# NestJS: How to get the Hostname in Controller method?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I have a **NestJS** application providing a REST-API.

How can I get the current **Hostname** inside a controller?

My controller function:

```
async find(@Param('uuid') uuid: string, @Req() req: Request): Promise<BlogDto> {}
```

I already can see the Path in the URL with this:

```
console.log(req.url);
```

But how can I find out the current hostname of my application?

I found examples like this, but this is not working because there is no Get-method on the Request-Headers-Object:

```
console.log(req.headers.get('host')); // not existing
```

Comment: how that `req.headers` looks like?

Comment: Have you tried req.host? the req.headers is an object it contains all the headers as well

Answer (score 0):

I have used `@Headers` decorator to receive `host` header:

```
@Headers('host') host: string
```